# Difference between class extends declarations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extends

I have been using the the extend declaration `class ClassB extends ClassA {}` for extending classes since I started using ES6 and since recently that was the only way I had seen it.

The other day while reading Yeoman documentation I noticed they were extending the class `module.exports = class extends ClassA {}`.

I figured these declarations must just be the different ways to say the exact same thing. I tested the following code to confirm my suspicions but it was not as clear as I had hoped:

```
class ClassA {
    constructor(width) {
        this.width = width
    }
}

let ClassB = class extends ClassA {
    constructor(width, height) {
        super(width)
        this.height = height
    }
}

class ClassC extends ClassA {
    constructor(width, height) {
        super(width)
        this.height = height
    }
}

let instanceB = new ClassB(10, 10)
let instanceC = new ClassC(10, 10)
```

When I inspected the demo in chrome I noticed that the constructors for variables `instanceB` and `instanceC` were slightly different:

```
- instanceB: ClassB
    - __proto__: ClassA
        - constructor: class extends
- instanceC: ClassC
    - __proto__: ClassA
        - constructor: class ClassC
```

My question is are Are these extend declarations exactly the same even though they are described slightly differently in the inspector?

Comment: I recommend to continue using class declarations. You can combine them with `export` or `export default` in ES6 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the same for all practical purposes. Considering

1. `module.exports = class extends ClassA {}`
2. `let ClassB = class extends ClassA {}`
3. `class ClassC extends ClassA`

then

- (1) will not have a [`.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), whereas `ClassB.name == "ClassB"` and `ClassC.name == "ClassC"`
- (3) will have the name inside the string returned by the [`.toString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString), whereas it returns `"class extends ClassA {}"` for the other two (this seems to be what the Chrome devtools inspection is based on, and I consider showing only `class extends` a bug and expect it to change - maybe to just `class` for unnamed classes)

Comment: Chrome appears to set `ClassB.name` to "ClassB" , and the name of IntanceB.contructor is shown after clicking on more open arrows in the console.  So the "bug" appears mostly about how the console operates. FYI the `Function.prototype.toString` method in Firefox appears to be an actual bug, producing function declarations (or exprssions) fpr class declarations (or expressions), and omits "extends _name_" clauses in all cases.

Comment: @Traktor53 Yes, the naming of instances is inferred fine, it's the short (unexpanded) representation of the constructor function that is (imo) mangled.

Comment: that was my initial thought also, but no longer (imho) think it should be changed: reporting "class extends _className_" provides immediate information that  the object was created by an anonymous class _expression_ rather than declaration. How many would notice  or care is anther question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are assigning it to a variable. Try
`class classB extends classA`
instead of:
`let classB = class extends...`